# Inter-jurisdictional arrest issues (USA, UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, trial, united-states

My question centers around this:

> It may harm your defense if you do not mention when questioned, something you later rely on in court.

Which is something I've heard told to arrested suspects in the UK. Here's my question.

If an American is arrested in the UK, and keeps his mouth shut despite the warning in the block quote, and (after the red tape with the consulates) stands trial in the UK, is his defense harmed, or is the simple explanation that "He is American, and treated UK officers like US officers," sufficient for the Jury?
[This Question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7039/failing-to-mention-when-questioned-something-you-later-rely-on-in-court) seems to imply that yes, it ought to be, as the item in the quote is for the defendant's benefit.

I'm also interested in the reverse. Suppose a UK suspect is arrested in US, and remembering the UK warning, speaks to the police. However, because he isn't a lawyer, phrases some aspects of his speech in a less than ideal manner, which the officers later use against him in court.

**How, and to what extent, have the US and UK defendants harmed their defense?**

Comment: I imagine the US-in-UK case is something like claiming  to be attempting to resolve a potential issue of safety or prevent a crime, but saying nothing about it when first responders arrive - if it was about safety or crime and you wanted it fixed, why didn't you get those responders to help you instead of remaining silent and getting arrested and letting the danger/crime go unresolved? Obviously if the UK-in-US case involves statements that are harmful to the defence, the defence has been harmed...

Comment: What the jury thinks is a matter for them. Counsel/ the judge woud probably explain, and if I were in the box that would be enough for me; but if a juror is not convinced, the defence has been harmed and it can't be undone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The law applies equally to everyone

The fact that the person misunderstood the law is irrelevant irrespective of the reason for it.

That said, in both cases the person would have access to a lawyer and consular assistance who could explain the law to them.

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure that it is "*may* harm your defence" for a reason: it needn't do so if one has a good reason to remain silent until trial. For example, one was especially tired, did not recall details of the time of the crime until having a chance to rest, or had been conditioned by advice tailored to a different legal system. The thing about harming your defence is that if there is not a good explanation for it, then (rational) inferences may be drawn from the fact of one's silence. But not irrational ones where it has a better and less disadvantageous explanation.